# Checking certain address/url and displaying part of html code in Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question.

Is it possible to check if my address / url contains part of string and display certain part of html code in Rails 4?

For example:
if address contain word users like this:
`http://example.com/users/1`
I want to add html code which should be displaying in this link like:

```
= link_to "Back to Profiles", "/?iframe=true"
```

but if it doesn't contain word users link should be visible as:

```
= link_to "Back", "/?iframe=true"
```

I tried to use `request.path` like:

```
- if request.path =~ /\/users/
  = link_to "Back to Profiles", "/?iframe=true"
- else
  = link_to "Back", "/?iframe=true"
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
- if request.original_url.include?("users")
  = link_to "Back to Profiles", "/?iframe=true"
- else
  = link_to "Back", "/?iframe=true"
```

Rails 3+

Answer (score 0):

Try request.path_info

```
= link_to "Back#{' to Profiles' if request.path_info =~ /^\/users/i}", "/?iframe=true"
```

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that I'm working on iframes and two links are almost the same. One is like `users/1/` and the other is `users/1?iframe=true`

I needed to add something like this:

```
- if request.original_url.match(/\?.*/)
  = link_to "Back to Profiles", "/?iframe=true"
- else
  = link_to "Back", "/?iframe=true"
```

@Nimir, than you for help!

Comment: This answer would be better as an edit to your original question (marked with EDIT)